# C#-WinForms || Multiple instances of Graphics for rotation

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+, gdi

im currently working on a school project which is basically a game that involves GDI-Winforms animations.
I chose my game to be something like prison break where you are trying to escape the prison while guards with light-torches are walking around the room.

So, i have the **Guard** class which represents the guard and has **A Path** to walk on. Furthermore, the guard can rotate in 90deg. angles. (animated to a certain degree)
When i rotate the guard, i actually rotate the **Graphics** object that was passed through the Form_Paint event:

```
    void Game_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        ply.Draw(e.Graphics); // Draws the player

        grd.Draw(e.Graphics); // Draws the guard
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, grd.GetPath()); // Draws the guard's path

    }
```

When i was dealing with only 1 guard, it was working great. Smooth and did the exactly what he was supposed to do.
When i tried to add 1 more guard, they started to freak out. Soon enough i figured out that its because im sending both guards **to draw the same instance of Graphics**. Which also means, both of them are rotating it.
Lets say one is rotating by -90, the other will too, but his **angle** class member variable will not be -90, then all hell breaks loose.

Rotation of graphics method (sits inside the guard class):

```
 public Graphics RotateGuard(Graphics g, Point pivot, float angle) // returns the rotated Graphics object
    {
        if (!float.IsNaN(angle))
        {
            using (Matrix m = new Matrix())
            {
                m.RotateAt(angle, pivot);
                g.Transform = m;
            }
        }
        return g;
    }
```

The next thing i did was to give each of them `this.CreateGraphics()`.

```
void Game_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        ply.Draw(e.Graphics); // Draws the player
        foreach (Guard grd in this.guards )
        {
            grd.Draw(this.CreateGraphics()); // Draws the guard
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, grd.GetPath()); // Draws the guard's path
        }        

    }
```

Then everything worked just fine. The only thing is, it seemed like it was really heavy for the GPU to process or something. It drew the guard once about every 5 frames less than he supposed to be drawn.

I googled but couldn't find anything but people saying that "There is no need to clone a Graphics object", but still, i can't think of any better WORKING solution.

How can i solve this problem nicely? 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you drawing the guards directly in Game or are you using a Managerclass?

Comment: @VictoriaS. Hello Victoria, i am sending the Guard object the e.Graphics from the Game_Paint (which is the main form in my case) then it draws it from within the class. 
Im not sure what "Managerclass" means.

Comment: Are your guards a seperate object in a seperate class? if Yes, a GuardManager.cs could keep a list of guards, where each of them is and which way they're facing. Your main form would only have to contact the GuardManager to know where everything is, in stead of doing all the work.

Comment: @VictoriaS. OP is using _WinForms_ not XNA

Comment: @Micky, I know. It's just an idea I'm sharing.

Comment: Is `RotateGuard` called from inside your `Guard.Draw`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateGraphics()` is a really bad idea. You should do all the drawing to the `Graphics` passed by `PaintEventArgs`.  So your initial code is just fine. However, what you need to do is to ensure that every object that receives a `Graphics` in its `Draw` method leaves it unchanged after doing its job. This can be achieved by using [Graphics.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.save(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Graphics.Restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.restore(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
class Guard
{
    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        var state = g.Save();
        try
        {
            // The actual drawing code
        }
        finally
        {
            g.Restore(state);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ivan, it does work, but still flicker. It draws the guard about 1/4 of the frames he **should** be drawn. (Lets say once every 180ms).
I tried tweaking the timer that `Invalidate()` s the form, but it is still flickering. Any idea why?

Comment: @Cybrus You can set double buffered mode for the control where the painting occurs. What type of control is `Game`?

Comment: The control is a Windows Form. I have set it to DoubleBuffered and it still flicker, but looks a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

After drawing with the rotated `Graphics` tool object simply call `e.Graphics.ResetTransform()`.

Also you may want to look into `Graphics.Save()` and `Graphics.Restore()` if you have made a few settings you want to return to.. It can save few states and  when done with them bring them back up. Very nice, at least if you keep count of what you are doing.

And, of course you **could** undo the Translation/Rotation by doing the reverse calls in the reverse order, but the other methods are simpler and made for just your case.

Note that `Graphics` doesn't **contain** any graphics, it is a **tool used to draw** into an associated `Bitmap` or onto a control's surface..

Finally: **Never, never** use `CreateGraphics` !!! Its results are **non-persistent**, which you want only very rarely..

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way is to maintain one overall transform and have a matrix for each thing you wish to draw.  Prior to drawing you multiply the current transform with the object's transform.  Afterwards you reset the transform before drawing next.

```
void Game_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.ResetTransform();

    g.MultiplyTransform (playerMatrix);
    ply.Draw(e.Graphics); // Draws the player
    g.ResetTransform();

    foreach (Guard grd in this.guards )
    {
        g.MultiplyTransform (grd.Matrix);
        grd.Draw(this.CreateGraphics()); // Draws the guard
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, grd.GetPath()); // Draws the guard's path

        g.ResetTransform();
    }        

}
```

Such concepts are similar to how things are done in 3D graphics such as Direct3D; XNA; OpenGL and Unity3D.

Comment: Ill be completely honest with you, i'm not too familiar with the Mathematic term of "Matrix" (I'm only 17y/o)
The rotation method i have posted is a tweaked version of something i found online. I do not understand Matrices too well at all. 
I did do a method which returns the last matrix that was rotated in the `RotateGuard()` method, but it looks like it doesn't work at all. (It does the giant, red X on the whole form.) If you could perhaps clarify what it should do, after i learn the basics of matrices i hope i will understand your code better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what it was, then i used what @Ivan did.

```
 void Game_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var saved = e.Graphics.Save();
        ply.Draw(e.Graphics); // Draws the player
        foreach (Guard grd in this.guards )
        {
            grd.Draw(e.Graphics); // Draws the guard

            e.Graphics.Restore(saved);
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, grd.GetPath()); // Draws the guard's path
        }



    }
```

All i had to do is instead of using `this.DoubleBuffered` i used  `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);` which at first i thought both does the same, but evidently it does not.
Then, i saved the current graphics state and re-drew it.

Thanks a lot for everyone!